Remote Control of NED2 Arm Robot Using VR
In my current project, I'm tasked with controlling a NED2 arm robot using a VR headset. The objective is to have the robot transmit data such as pose, trajectory, and gripper state, while the VR interface assists in visualizing this information. Additionally, there's a requirement for rendering the robot in a 3D model, allowing real-time synchronization between the virtual environment and the physical robot's movements. It's important to note that the robot and VR headset can operate from separate locations, enabling remote control with minimal latency. What protocol would be best suited for efficient data transfer in this scenario?
I have been studying WebSocket, MQTT, OPC UA, and Modbus protocols, but I am uncertain which one would be the most suitable for my project. Additionally, I am curious if there are any other protocols that might be better suited for this application.
